# Invalid free() only when running larger text files through C program

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, valgrind

Ive been working on a project which takes whole files as single strings and manipulates them in various ways, but keep getting stuck on a valgrind error when running text files bigger than around ~500 characters. Some code for reference:

**My Program:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 20
#define MAX_WORDS 50

// REQUIRED PROTOTYPES

char * readFile (char * filename);

char * stretchMe (char * aStringToStretch);

int splitMe (char * aStringToSplit, char static2D [MAX_WORDS][MAX_LENGTH]);

int shrinkMe (char * aStringToShrink);

bool isItAPalindrome (char * aString);

void printSuffixes (char * aString, int whichWord, char * desiredSuffix);

// Custom Functions

int checkPunctuation(char x);

// Main

int main(int argc, char **argvs)
{ 
    if(argc < 2)
    {
        puts("Wrong usage when executing");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    puts("\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
    printf("Txt File: [%s]\n", argvs[1]);
    puts("\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");

    char *ioFileString;
    ioFileString = readFile(argvs[1]);
    printf("%s", ioFileString);

    puts("\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
    /*
    char *stretchedIoFileString;
    stretchedIoFileString = stretchMe(ioFileString);
    printf("%s", stretchedIoFileString);
    free(stretchedIoFileString);
    */
    puts("\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");

    char static2D [MAX_WORDS][MAX_LENGTH];
    int wordsCounted = splitMe(ioFileString, static2D);
    printf("Word Count :[%d]", wordsCounted);

    puts("\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");

    free(ioFileString);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

char * readFile (char * filename)
{
    FILE *fp = NULL; // Initialize file pointer

    fp = fopen(filename, "r"); // Open file

    if(fp == NULL) // Check if file was found
    {
        printf("Error: Could not find file %s, please try again", filename);
        exit(-1); // Error
    }

    // First count number of characters in file
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END); // Seek to end of file
    int cCount = ftell(fp); // Counts amount of characters in file, add one for endline.
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET); // Seek back to the beginning of the file

    char *buffer = calloc((cCount+1), sizeof(char));

    if(buffer == NULL)
    {
        puts("Malloc Failed, exiting");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int numRead = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), cCount, fp);

    buffer[cCount] = '\0';

    if(numRead != cCount)
    {
        puts("Did not read correctly, exiting.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return buffer;
}

char * stretchMe (char * aStringToStretch)
{
    const int stringLength = strlen(aStringToStretch);

    int *userInput = calloc(stringLength, sizeof(int));

    int newStringLength = 0;

    printf("Please enter %d integers sequentially:\n", stringLength);

    int inUser;

    for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++)
    {
        //scanf("%d", &inUser);

        inUser = 2;

        userInput[i] = inUser;

        if(userInput[i] < 1)
        {
            printf("\nInvalid value: values must be positive\n");
            i--;
        }
        else
        {
            newStringLength = newStringLength + userInput[i];
        }
    }

    char *stretchedString = malloc(sizeof(char)*(newStringLength + 1));

    int index = 0;

    for (int i  = 0; i < stringLength; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < userInput[i]; j++)
        {
            stretchedString[index] = aStringToStretch[i];
            index++;
        }
    }

    stretchedString[index] = '\0';

    free(userInput);

    return stretchedString;
}

int splitMe (char * aStringToSplit, char static2D [MAX_WORDS][MAX_LENGTH])
{
    const int stringLength = strlen(aStringToSplit);
    const char delim[] = " \n";

    char *buffer = calloc(stringLength+1, sizeof(char)); // Alloc memory for buffer for strtok();
    strcpy(buffer, aStringToSplit); // Copy string to buffer

    char *token;
    token = strtok(buffer, delim);

    int wordCount = 0;
    while(token != NULL)
    {
        puts("Loops");
        printf("%d", wordCount);
        strcpy(static2D[wordCount], buffer);
        wordCount++;

        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }

    free(buffer);

    return wordCount;
}

/*int shrinkMe (char * aStringToShrink)
{
    int puncCount = 0;
    int tempIndex = 0;

    int stringLength = strlen(aStringToShrink);

    char *tempShrinked = malloc(sizeof(char)*stringLength);

    for(int i = 0; aStringToShrink[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if(checkPunctuation(aStringToShrink[i]) == 1)
        {
            puncCount++;
        }
        else
        {
            tempShrinked[tempIndex] = aStringToShrink[i];
            tempIndex++;
        }
    }

    tempShrinked[tempIndex] = '\0';
    
    strcpy(aStringToShrink, tempShrinked);

    printf("%s", tempShrinked);
    printf("%s", aStringToShrink);
    return puncCount;
}

bool isItAPalindrome (char * aString)
{
    return true;
}

void printSuffixes (char * aString, int whichWord, char * desiredSuffix)
{

}*/

int checkPunctuation(char x)
{
    switch (x)
    {  
    case '.':
    case ':':
    case ';':
    case '?':
    case '!':
        return 1; // If any of the above cases are found, the case flows down the line to the last
        break;

    default:
        return 0;
        break;
    }
}
```

I get no errors when calling `readFile();` by itself, it allocates and frees fine. It is only when it is a larger file and the function `splitMe();` is called, Valgrind reports 2 errors:

```
==19545== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==19545==    at 0x48369AB: free (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==19545==    by 0x109335: main (main.c:35)
==19545==  Address 0x65685404a26730 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==19545== 
==19545== 
==19545== HEAP SUMMARY:
==19545==     in use at exit: 733 bytes in 1 blocks
==19545==   total heap usage: 7 allocs, 7 frees, 15,627 bytes allocated
==19545== 
==19545== Searching for pointers to 1 not-freed blocks
==19545== Checked 67,600 bytes
==19545== 
==19545== 733 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==19545==    at 0x4837B65: calloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==19545==    by 0x1093E0: readFile (functions.c:24)
==19545==    by 0x10928B: main (main.c:17)
==19545== 
==19545== LEAK SUMMARY:
==19545==    definitely lost: 733 bytes in 1 blocks
==19545==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19545==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19545==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19545==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19545== 
==19545== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==19545== 
==19545== 1 errors in context 1 of 2:
==19545== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==19545==    at 0x48369AB: free (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==19545==    by 0x109335: main (main.c:35)
==19545==  Address 0x65685404a26730 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==19545== 
==19545== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

*(The 733 bytes is the space allocated by that first calloc in readFile)*

Im assuming maybe it has something to do with a combination of the `calloc();` in readFile and the `strcpy();` in splitMe? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Where's `stretchMe()`, add the full code please.

Comment: What is `MAX_WORDS` and `MAX_LENGTH`? You pass an array with those dimensions into  `splitMe` but make no attempt to do bounds checking. So a memory corruption possibility there. Please provide complete code as a [mre] (and best to give it in one complete block rather than broken up so that others can copy easily).

Comment: @SparKot I initially didnt add it because it was fully commented out in my code, it has now been added

Comment: @kaylum They are constants that are confirmed to not go over these amounts for the project Im working on. Also I have reposted with all code collected. Thanks.

Comment: Yes and how about the possible memory corruption due to no bounds checking? Do you understand and agree that is a problem? That would explain why larger files result in unexpected results.

Comment: The method of estimating file size with `fseek` doesn't work for text streams, either don't rely on this , or open the file in binary mode

Comment: @KairosJk put the test in there anyway because its the right thing to do. And then you can tell whoever told you that those limits were not going to be blown that they were wrong

Comment: @pm100 Just did, solved everything, feel stupid lol. Thanks

Comment: Can you confirm there is a leak?

Comment: @SparKot There was, but after added the conditionals for the `calloc`s Its been fixed. It all works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for a start you make the huge assumption that you can fit the entire file into memory. But dont check that it worked

```
// First count number of characters in file
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END); // Seek to end of file
int cCount = ftell(fp); // Counts amount of characters in file, add one for endline.
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET); // Seek back to the beginning of the file


char* buffer = calloc((cCount + 1), sizeof(char));

int numRead = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), cCount, fp);
```

You have to check the return from calloc

then at the start of splitME even if that one worked you copy the entire file to another heap allocation with no test if it worked.

```
const int stringLength = strlen(aStringToSplit);
const char delim[] = " \n";

char* buffer = calloc(stringLength + 1, sizeof(char)); // Alloc memory for buffer for strtok(); <<<<=== check this retunrn
strcpy(buffer, aStringToSplit); // Copy string to buffer
```

so you are attempting to hold 2 copies of the file in memory at once

With a 500 byte file this is probably OK, but this is very poor code

The actual reason you are failing is because you don't check to see if you have > MAX_WORDS of if a word is larger than MAX_LENGTH

Also note that you program won't work on windows. You find the length of the file including all the CRLFs at the end of the line, but open the file in text mode, fread will drop the LFs so your test to see if you read the correct number of chars will fail

Comment: Looking back this should have been obvious to me. Added some simple conditionals and all works fine now. In the future, how would I prevent holding two copies and wasting a large amount of memory but still being able to use strtok()? Thanks again for the response.

Comment: @KairosJk the second allocation is a total waste of time, just use `aStringToSplit` directly in splitMe, strtok will work perfectly well on it.

Comment: What if I want to keep aStringToSplit unedited? Doesnt strtok directly edit up a string that is inputted into tokens?

Comment: if you want to preserve it then yes, you need to make another copy (or reread the file)